# HTML button not working on mobile device when connected to local host server on laptop

Tags: html, node.js, web, electron, local

My problem is that localhost port 3000 is hosting a Nodejs web-app and this web-app has a button that sends a message to another electron app hosted on the same laptop. So you press the button and a message is sent through a WebSocket to port 1080 that the electron app is listening to. This works great and exactly how it should.

The problem is when I go to the Nodejs app from my mobile phone I connect to my laptop IP and port 3000. This displays the page but when I press the button on my mobile phone nothing happens to my electron app. It's like the electron app does not receive the message from my phone web browser.

Any help would be appreciated. Below is the code for my buttons which work fine when accessing from my laptop.

```
div(class='btn_container')
    button(class='good_lift lift_btn' onclick='is_good_lift("true")') Lift is Good

    button(class='bad_lift lift_btn' onclick='is_good_lift("false")') Lift is Bad
```

EDIT: I found the answer. I still had localhost instead of the local IP. So on mobile it was sending to the phones localhost

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I still had localhost instead of the local IP. So on mobile it was sending to the phones localhost